# WebSphere Liberty Profile JCA

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am downloading WebSphere Liberty profile V8.5.5.2 with the JCA feature. And i get the message..

The following items installed successfully:
-Liberty Profile V8.5.5.2 Runtime

The following items failed to install:
- Connection Architecture (JCA)
Install process failed with exit value 20: CWWKF1007E: An error occurred while downloading the Subsystem archive to C:Users\monte\AppData\Local\Temp\libertyfeature65554836009278578-0083.esa, exception Connection timed out:connect.

(*note i was not able to cut and paste the above text. Seems the panel does not allow cut.)

I am using Eclipse clean install
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627.

Is JCA avaliable in this release? I get the install option to include it with 8.5.5.2.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Only just seen this question and noticed it's a few months old, so probably already answered, but in case others come across it, yes, JCA is available on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.2.